# Facebook Commenting is posting user comments twice

Tags: duplicates, double, comments

When users posts comments, they are appearing twice: once as a comment, and once as a reply to that comment.  For an example, see the bottom of this page:

http://www.jewishjournal.com/suissas_blog/item/in_egypt_food_over_allah

Any idea why this double posting is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a Facebook bug that they have known about since July 8 -- waiting on a fix from Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/489244604487290